# Generating unique ID for different dropdown selected

Tags: unique, id

I've a drop down consisting the names of different banks for ex. HDFC, AXIS , ICICI etc. How to generate unique Id for eace branch suppose for HDFC is selected then the unique Id will be HDFC0000, HDFC0001, HDFC0002 and so on for AXIS it will be AXIS0000, AXIS0001 etc ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should create two lists.
2. X list for different banks and Y list for its branches.
3. Lookup the bank name column from X list into Y list.
4. Create items for all the different branches in Y list.
5. Create a calculated column in Y list for e.g. BankId (column name)
   and use the below formula to concat bank name and Id

   =[BankName]&[Id]

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to automatically create a new ID as each branch is added, you will need to use a workflow.

If you want a unique ID, but it does not need to start with 1 for each bank, then build a calculated column using the Bank from the choice list and the list item's ID property.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with relying on the ID value. If you edit the properties of your entry - ID is not available to the Edit card. The calculated field will re-calc with ID being null and will update your calculated field value (thus - it's not constant)